# vertical lines with full height between divs

Tags: html, css

I have three divs (left, mid and right) and these divs don't have an exact height, because it depends on how many rows text are inside the div.
Now I want vertical lines (which seperate the three divs) through the whole height of the users monitor, no matter how high the divs are.

How can I do this? Because , as you can see in the css-code, border-right/border-left don't work for me.

**Intention**
[image]
**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content_left"></div>
    <div class="content_mid"></div>
    <div class="content_right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {  
    line-height: 1.1;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px; /* because there is a top-menu which is 36px high */
    left: 70px; /* because there is a side-menu which is 70px wide */
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.content_left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 22.5%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.content_mid {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.content_right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 22.5%;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

**Edit 1:** I would like to have these seperate-lines 1px wide and I cannot set the height of content_left, content_mid, content_right to 100% because I have resizeable boxes in these divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh0972Lm/)

The HTML structure is a bit more complicated than yours:

```
<div class="menu-top">Menu top</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu-left">Menu left</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="column-content">
                 <h1>Column 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="column-content">
                 <h1>Column 2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="column-content">
                <h1>Column 3</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: #3498DB;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
.menu-left {
    height: calc(100vh - 36px);
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #59ABE3;
}
.content {
    width: calc(100vw - 70px);
    height: calc(100vh - 36px);
    background-color: #E4F1FE;
    display: flex;
}
.column {
    flex: 33;
    border-left: 1px solid hotpink;
}
.column:first-of-type {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can actually fake it using `background-color` for the parent.

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */

.parent {background-color: #f99; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
.parent .col {float: left; background-color: #fff; height: 100%; margin: 0.5%; width: 32.25%; position: relative;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col">
    <p>I am one line!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>I am three lines!</p>
    <p>I am three lines!</p>
    <p>I am three lines!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>I am two lines!</p>
    <p>I am two lines!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/hefefawilu/1**

Comment: Sry, I didn't wrote it in the first post. I would like to have the seperate-line 1px wide. And I cannot set the height of .col to 100% because I have resizable boxes in the left and the right div.

Answer (score 3):

Just Created a fiddle using your code.
See and let me know if this solves your issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/knxd0htm/

Add this part of code to make it work

```
**HTML:**

<div class="content">
    <div class="content_left">a</div>
    <div class="full-height one"></div>
    <div class="content_mid">b</div>
    <div class="full-height two"></div>
    <div class="content_right">c</div>
</div>

**CSS**

/**** CODE ****/
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.content {
    height: calc(100%-36px);
    min-height: calc(100%-36px);
}
.full-height {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}

.full-height.one {
    left: 22.5%;
}
.full-height.two {
    right: 22.5%;
}
/**** CODE ****/
```

Comment: @KlippOhei: The accepted answer contains display :flex which is not supported by IE9. Also, this answer has minimal code changes into the code you gave,  as compared to accepted answer. Still, its your question... Your Choice !!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without adding an extra HTML by using Pseudo selectors. I've also tidied up some of the code that works out widths :).

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;  
}
html, body {  
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body {
  position:relative;  
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.content {
  line-height: 1.1;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  /* because there is a top-menu which is 36px high */
  left: 70px;
  /* because there is a side-menu which is 70px wide */
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.content_left {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(25% - 35px);
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.content_mid {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.content_right {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(25% - 35px);
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.content:before {
  content: '';
  border-left:1px solid #ccc;
  width:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:25%;
  bottom:0;
}
.content:after {
  content: '';
  border-right:1px solid #ccc;
  width:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:25%;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content_left"></div>
  <div class="content_mid"></div>
  <div class="content_right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The most simplest approach in my opinion